# Regexp: how to match everythings that is not into a pattern?

Tags: php, regex

I want to match everything in a string that does **not** match a given pattern; for example `[a-z]`.

Given the string `abc4jkf8 4à3in`, I need to match `48 4à3`.

I've tried with `([a-z])+(?![a-z])` but this matches exactly the opposite of what I need. With the string above, this regexp matches `abcjkfin`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use a negative set:

```
([^a-z]+)
```

Comment: So, you didn't tryed that one.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match_all('/([^a-z]+)/si', $code, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$unmached = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
    $unmached .= $result[0][$i];
}
echo $unmached;
```

`[^a-z]` matches every character that is not a-z.

Answer (score 2):

why not use preg_replace.

```
$string = "abc4jkf8 4à3in";
echo preg_replace("/[a-z]/", "", $string);
```

this gives the desired result

Answer (score 1):

You need to match any charater that is no alpha. The ^ tells not to match alpha chars

```
[^a-z]*
```

Comment: Does a-z contain umlauts or letters with accents like ä, ü, á, é?

Comment: @Simon: no, AFAIK `òèàìù` are not included into the [a-z] set

Comment: @Simon: @DaNiel is right, a-z does not include accents. If you wanted to match them you may need to add them yourself like [àä]

Comment: @Simon: or use `\p{IsLetter}`, which includes *all* Unicode accented characters you could ever imagine (negative character class: `\P{IsLetter}` to match anything *not* a letter). You can use the character shortcuts inside and outside a character class.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = "abc4jkf8 4à3in";

function stringConcat($a, $b) { return $a.$b; }

if (preg_match_all("/[^a-z]/", $a, $matches)) {
    echo array_reduce(reset($matches), 'stringConcat');
}
```

gives what you want.

Comment: That's similar to what im doing now, but i want to do it with just 1 preg_replace